# Salesforce API login Status=Server Error, StatusCode=500

Tags: apex, api, login

In the past i  implemented following example 
http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/verifying-password

in order to login a user via API:

I've exactly same code and it worked for  1year.
Now it s not working anymore, response call is:

```
HttpResponse[Status=Server Error, StatusCode=500]
```

I m wondering if something (endpoint, request format) has changed with Winter 15 release.
Do you know something about?

Comment: All soap faults are sent with a 500 status code (as per the SOAP 1.1 spec). you'll want to grab the body and see what the soap fault says. It could be an IP range change that means you need to also send the api security token

Comment: Thanks Superfell, I ve added my ip to the trusted but no luck. Do i need to check some other thing?

Comment: You need to look at the response body of your request it'll tell you whats wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the issue is around the security token and the Trusted IP Ranges in the Network Access Security Controls.

Something to check, look for failed logins under `Administration Setup > Manage Users > Login History`. If you see the Status message "Failed: API security token required" then the requesting Salesforce IP address isn't trusted.

If the IP address that the login request is coming from isn't trusted Salesforce will reject it unless you append the security token on the end of the password.

So your options are:

1. Modify the Visualforce page to prompt the user to append their security token. You can't get this in Apex code. It is emailed to the user using the Reset my Security Token link.
2. Add the requesting Salesforce servers IP address to the Trusted IP addresses under `Administration Setup > Securtiy Controls > Network Access: Trusted IP Ranges`. You could also check [Salesforce IP Address to whitelist](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Salesforce-IP-Address-to-whitelist&language=en_US)

---

**This isn't so applicable anymore, but does provide a sample working version from anonymous apex**

<strike>It would appear that the sample code isn't building a valid SOAP POST request for the partner API. In particular, it is missing the body element. I modified the way the XML is created and got it working</strike>.

The request body should look something like:

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>   <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
>     <env:Header />
>     <env:Body>
>       <login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
>         <username>username@example.com</username>
>         <password>UserPasswordqFOSeCuRiTyTokEn9v6DeJysC</password>
>       </login>
>     </env:Body>
>   </env:Envelope>

Here is the hastily modified login Soap message. Note the additional XML declaration <strike>and **Body** plus</strike> Header elements in the `xmlOutput`.

```
String LOGIN_DOMAIN = 'login'; //other options: test, prerellogin.pre
String username = UserInfo.getUsername();
String password = 'password'; // + security token

XmlStreamWriter w = new XmlStreamWriter();
w.writeStartElement('', 'login', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com');
w.writeNamespace('', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com');

w.writeStartElement('', 'username', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com');
w.writeCharacters(username);
w.writeEndElement();

w.writeStartElement('', 'password', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com');
w.writeCharacters(password);
w.writeEndElement();

w.writeEndElement();

String xmlOutput = 
      '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n'
      + '<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
      + '<Header />' 
      + '<Body>' 
      + w.getXmlString() 
      + '</Body>'
      + '</Envelope>';
w.close();

System.debug(xmlOutput);

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://' + LOGIN_DOMAIN + '.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/22.0');
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
request.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');

request.setBody(xmlOutput);

//basically if there is a loginResponse element, then login succeeded; else there
//  would be soap fault element after body
Boolean verified = (new Http()).send(request).getBodyDocument().getRootElement()
  .getChildElement('Body','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
  .getChildElement('loginResponse','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com') != null;

if(verified) { System.debug('Correct password!'); }
else { System.debug('Incorrect password!');
```

Comment: Look more closely at the sample code, Body is there, an empty Header isn't needed.

Comment: That s great Daniel! Thanks a lot. There is only one point that isn t clear to me: now you are adding the security token to the password.Is it required?Is there a method in apex to get a token for  user?Because in my old code i wasn t using them.

Comment: @superfell Quite right, I'm not sure where I misplaced it in converting to anonymous apex.

Comment: @MarcoDev I was wrong about the Body missing in the request. The security token is required when logging in from an untrusted IP address. Check your Network Access settings. If the IP isn't there you will need the security token.

Comment: I see under my user detail "Failed: API security token required" but i ve added myip address to the trusted. Is there some other security setting to check?

Comment: @MarcoDev It's not your IP address that you need to add. It is that of the Salesforce Server running the Apex code that needs to be added. For some reason the Login History masks this behind the "Salesforce.com IP" Source IP value.

Comment: Thanks again.  How can i know the IP of Salesforce Server running the Apex code?

Comment: @MarcoDev best to take the IP ranges listed in the [linked official documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Salesforce-IP-Address-to-whitelist&language=en_US). Be aware that these may [change over time](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23272/salesforce-new-ip-addresses-issue).

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I have tried to insert this IP whitelist in Network Access but it is not working.Do you have some other advice?

Comment: @MarcoDev Is the failed login appearing in the Login History?

Comment: yes it is. Status = Failed: API security token required

Comment: @MarcoDev First, try appending the Security Token just to verify everything else is working. If that allows you to login, you must be missing an IP address in the Trusted IP ranges.

Comment: I had just tried with the security token, and it works. I also tried to add Trusted IP ranges (the one specified in the whitelist) but it does not work.

Comment: @MarcoDev That it works with the Security Token makes me think it is either a missing IP address or some [specific security permission](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_concepts_security.htm#topic-title_login_token). What pod/server are you on? E.g. na5. Can you change the endpoint to a remote site to verify the actual Salesforce IP address externally?

Comment: Hi Daniel, do you know a tool that can provide this service? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MarcoDev I'd tend just to throw something together quickly that listens on a configured port and public IP address. I think SOAP UI could do it, but setting it up on a public IP address could be a bit of an exercise.